# Joomla session expiring quickly

Tags: joomla1.5

I am using joomla 1.5 for my site.

I had set the session life time to 12000 minutes(one week) in global configuration file. But session expires within 10-15 minutes.

Is there any other place we need to mention the value?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to find something like this

```
session.cookie_lifetime
session.gc_maxlifetime
```

in your code (and in .htaccess too). Maybe session lifetime is set somewhere in code